# Plotting timedelta lap times

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, timedelta

I'm trying to compare lap times between drivers so I tried to plot a line graph. Everything looks good, however, the y axis isn't correct.

The data looks like this:

```
    driverId    lap_num    lap_time
0   driver1     1          00:01:27.853000
1   driver1     2          00:01:22.182000
2   driver1     3          00:01:21.611000
3   driver1     4          00:01:20.812000
4   driver1     5          00:01:20.772000
5   driver1     6          00:01:20.657000
```

lap_time was converted from string into timedelta.

The code I used to plot the graph:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for driver in driver_list:
    ax.plot(df[df['driver']==driver].lap_num, df[df['driver']==driver].lap_time, label=driver)

ax.set_xlabel("Lap Number")
ax.set_ylabel("Time")
```

[image]

How do I fix the y axis?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the lap_time to seconds and then plot it:

```
df['lap_time'] = df['lap_time'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
```

Comment: is there a way to display it as minutes and seconds?

Comment: What exactly do u mean by `minutes and seconds`?